# I'm working with Javascript, but VS Code gives me typescript intellisense. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

It is incredibly annoying because it gives me false Errors. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the Deno extension enabled. I just disabled it for that workspace and it fixed itself.